# Why is ResponseEntity<Foo> geting a different result to ResponseEntity<String>?

Tags: java, api, rest, spring-mvc

For my Java Spring Boot Application (v2.7.12), I am performing a GET request using `restTemplate.exchange()` which passes in my correct `url`, `HttpEntity` with the correct headers, and response type `Profile.class`.

It assigns this to `ResponseEntity<Profile> response`

```
ResponseEntity<Profile> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Profile.class);
```

Now,
when I assign it to a String type: `ResponseEntity<String> response` instead of Profile, the `response.getBody()` returns the correct json body, with the correct data: `name: random`

```
<200,{"user":{"username='instagram', full_name='instagram'}
```

However,
when I assign it to a Profile type: `ResponseEntity<Profile> response`, it returns the correct json body, but with invalid data: `name: null`

```
<200,{"user":{"username='null', full_name='null'}
```

What I want to do is assign the exact API attributes to my Profile model class, without needing to parse JSON myself for the HTML type.

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class Profile {
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;
    @JsonProperty("full_name")
    private String full_name;
    @JsonProperty("is_private")
    private boolean is_private;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("profile_pic_url")
    private String profile_pic_url;
    @JsonProperty("follower_count")
    private int follower_count;
    @JsonProperty("following_count")
    private int following_count;
    @JsonProperty("biography")
    private String biography;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

This is my restTemplate:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder){
        return builder.build();
    }
```

I know this issue has an easy workaround. I have tried using Jackson API to parse JSON from the String type response body, but I wish this to be Plan B.

I have tried changing the URL formatting, and it makes no difference.
The headers are fine.
The API itself is not wrong.

```
Profile profile = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Profile.class)
```

I tried using `.getForObject` which worked before, but I needed to pass in headers, and it can't do that.

Comment: Don't post images of codes. Put the actual code in your question. As far as I can see, the data you're looking for is wrapped in a root `user` object in the retrieved JSON. This is why your deserialization is not working as expected. You have some options to deal with it.

Comment: @Matheus I've changed the images to code. I've fixed it by using JsonNode to retrieve the user object, then using ObjectMapper to map that to my Profile automatically.

Comment: I've posted a answer, check to see if this helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has a root element named `user`. You're trying to deserialize assuming that there's no root element. That's why it is not working, Jackson tries to find the fields of the `Profile` class on the root, but it never finds any of them, because they are wrapped into another object.

First, configure your `ObjectMapper` this way (preferably put this code in a `@Configuration` annotated class:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    
    return objectMapper;
}
```

This will tell object mapper to allow deserialization with root value.

Now, annotate your `Profile` class with `@JsonRootName`:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
public class Profile {
    // ...
}
```

This way, on deserialization, Jackson will unwrap your value before deserializing the JSON into a `Profile` object.